# How to setup a l2tp VPN using strongSwan

Tags: debian, vpn, xl2tpd

I have found several guides to set up a l2tp VPN using openSwan, but I'd like to use strongSwan because I'm setting up a ikev2 VPN aswell, and I can't do it with openSwan.
Do you know if there's a way to apply openSwan settings to strongSwan to set up a l2tp vpn?

I can post the link of the guide if required.

I am using Debian.